# Why is laravel collection mapping array elements differently?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

Using Laravel version 5.4.

Code:

```
collect(['3a', '4b'])->map('intval')->all();
```

Expected result: `[3, 4]`

But instead the line above returns `[3, 0]` - i.e. the first element is transformed correctly, while the second isn't?

What's happening here?

Noteworthy, I'm getting the correct result with the native php array_map function:

```
// returns [3, 4]
array_map('intval', ['3a', '4b']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand exactly what is happening we can check the Collection class source code where we find the map function

```
public function map(callable $callback)
{
    $keys = array_keys($this->items);

    $items = array_map($callback, $this->items, $keys);

    return new static(array_combine($keys, $items));
}
```

So what laravel does it actually adds the keys as well to the array_map function call, which ultimately produces this call `array_map('intval', ['3a', '4b'], [0, 1])`

This will call `intval('3a', 0)` and `intval('4b', 1)` respectively, which as expected will yield 3 and 0, because the second parameter of intval according to the [official PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) is actually the base.

Laravel adds the keys because sometimes you might use them in your map callback as such

```
$collection->map(function($item, $key) { ... });
```

Comment: okay, this makes sense. Thanks for the explanation! I was close to posting a bug to the official tracker.

Answer (score 1):

if you try according to the laravel collection map syntax it yields the expected result

```
collect(['3a', '4b'])->map(function($item){
   return intval($item);
})->all();
```

Result

```
[3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it, this happens, because `map()` passes collection keys as third argument:

```
array_map($callback, $this->items, $keys);
```

So:

```
array_map('intval', ['3a', '4b'], [0, 1]); // Result is [3, 0]
array_map('intval', ['3a', '4b']); // Result is [3, 4]
```